# Expectation of stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm not able to understand why $$E\bigg[\int_0^tB_s^3dBs\bigg]=0$$
it would be true if $B_s^3 \in \Lambda^2$ but it seems to me that $B_s^3\in \Lambda^2_{loc}$

Comment: What is the definition of $\Lambda^2?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x):=x^4/4$. Then, using Itô's lemma,
$$
f(B_t)=\int_0^t f'(B_s)\,dB_s+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t f''(B_s)ds=\int_0^t B_s^3 \,dB_s+\frac{3}{2}\int_0^t B_s^2\,ds,
$$
and, therefore,
$$
\mathsf{E}\left[\int_0^t B_s^3 \,dB_s\right]=\frac{3}{4}t^2-\frac{3}{4}t^2
=0.$$

Comment: For those not used to stochastic calculus, it's probably good to note that Tonelli was used here.